# Issue with file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

//views/myproject/testupload.php

```
  <a class="btn pull-right btn btn-primary"
       href="<?= site_url("myproject/upload/") ?>"><?= lang('upload') ?></a>
```

//views/myproject/upload.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url('myproject/do_upload'));?>
<?=form_line('', form_upload('userfile', $this->form_validation->set_value('userfile')));?>
<?=form_submit('upload', lang('action_upload'), 'class="btn btn-primary"');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

//Controller/myproject/test.php

```
public function upload()
{
    $this->output->view('analytics/kysim/upload');
}

public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = 'C:/test/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'txt';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $name_file = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name_file))
    {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
        die();
        //$this->load->view('upload', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($data);
        die();
        //$this->load->view('success', $data);
    }
}
```

I am not able to upload a file to a specified location(C://test).var_dump($name_file) displays the uploaded file name.
$this->upload->do_upload($name_file) returns false and so var_dump($error) displays the `error message "error" => "<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p><p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>""`

Any help on uploading the file to specified location(C://test) would be appreciated.

Comment: $config['upload_path']          = 'C:\test\' should be.

Comment: @Sanjay that doesnt work

Comment: Does Apache have access to `C:/test` I would doubt it. Try uploading to a folder in your document root directory, does that work?

Comment: Although `"<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>` sounds like maybe you file input name is wrong

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

***Note*** : make sure your `c` drive has `test` folder which in turn have `writable` permission

*Your `do_upload` method should be like this :*

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']  = 'C:\test\\';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (! empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
    {
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            var_dump($data);
            die();
        }
    } 
}
```

Your form should be like this :

```
<?php 
  echo form_open_multipart('myproject/do_upload');
  echo form_line('', form_upload('userfile', $this->form_validation->set_value('userfile')));
  echo form_submit('upload', lang('action_upload'), 'class="btn btn-primary"');
  echo form_close();
?>
```

For more :  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: did my answer helps you

Comment: @pradeepThe issue was with upload path..i fixed it using temp system $config['upload_path']      = sys_get_temp_dir();

Comment: ya its for the live server but my answer working on localhost correctly u not mention that u working on live server

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help you:-
https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/